# Drag and drop on Angular material nested tree

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to implement drag and drop on Angular material nested tree.
The tree itself and drag and drop logic work well.
The problem is that I can't target the correct node to drop the dragged element inside
For example I have such structure:

[image]

if I will try to change the location of the element, for example Child1 form Group2 and move it to Group1, it is not gonna to work correctly
[image]
=>

[image]

As you can see Child1 is now on the same level as Group1 and Group2. I'd like to mention again that the drop() function is working right as it returns correct indices. It just changes the element position in array according to indices it receives what means that it gets wrong indices form the beginning
[image]

So that the problem is supposed to be in markup or css.
I've spend a lot of hours trying to understand this issue. Hope you help me.

This is simplified code of my material tree:

```
        <mat-tree [dataSource]="DataSource" [treeControl]="TreeControl" cdkDropList
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="node">
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center"
                            [class.bg-primary]="selected && node.id === selected.id">
                            <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [disabled]="node.isEmpty">
                                <mat-icon insert="true">
                                    {{TreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                                </mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul [class.primary]="selected && node.id === selected.id"
                        [class.tree-invisible]="!TreeControl.isExpanded(node) ">
                        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </mat-nested-tree-node>
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="node">
                <li>
                    {{node.id}}: {{node.caption}} &nbsp;
                    <a matTooltip="Open Test Suite" [routerLink]="['/link', node.id]">
                        <mat-icon inline="true">
                            open_in_new
                        </mat-icon>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </mat-tree-node>
            <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: isLoadMore">
                <p>and {{node.name}} more...</p>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Load" (click)="loadMore(node.id)">
                    <mat-icon>loop</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-tree-node>
        </mat-tree>
```